# how to show data of four table in one crystal report using vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a society project. I am using sql database and vb.net. I have four tables on the database as follows.

1. Registration
2. Nominee
3. MemberDetail
4. MachineryDetail

I want to show data from all four table in one crystal report. I tried to do this using inbuilt sql query creator of vs 2010 but it returns 0 row while data existed in database. I also create a dataset and a table to fill all and tried to show on crystal report but result is zero. my query is as follows -

```
SELECT        Registration.RegID, Registration.BoardNo, Registration.Name, Registration.Gender, Registration.DOB, Registration.RationCardNo, Registration.F_H_Name, 
                     Registration.VoterID, Registration.Eligibility, Registration.PanNo, Registration.Categary, Registration.BankAcNo, Registration.Bussiness, Registration.Phone, 
                     Registration.Address, Registration.Photo, Nominee.NomineeName, Nominee.Relation, Nominee.Adult, Nominee.NDOB, Nominee.Guard_Address, 
                     Nominee.EnrollDate, MemberDetail.F_M_Number, MemberDetail.No_of_Dependent, MemberDetail.Land_Owned, MemberDetail.HouseNo, MemberDetail.MAddress, 
                     MemberDetail.BuiltArea, MemberDetail.HCost, MachinaryDetail.Head, MachinaryDetail.Number, MachinaryDetail.MCost
FROM            MachinaryDetail INNER JOIN
                     MemberDetail ON MachinaryDetail.RegID = MemberDetail.RegID INNER JOIN
                     Nominee ON MachinaryDetail.RegID = Nominee.RegID INNER JOIN
                     Registration ON MachinaryDetail.RegID = Registration.RegID
WHERE Registration.RegID='BS-ksd2'
```

Comment: Does this query return correct results if you run it in SSMS?

Comment: By the way, all your tables have column called RegID, so this part in your query will cause an error. `RegID='BS-ksd2'` Are you sure it even runs?

Comment: @JamesZ sorry! my mistake. it is Registration.RegID

Comment: it return 0 rows

Comment: Check all the table separately, one (or more) of them doesn't have any rows for RegID='BS-ksd2'. Either fix your data or use outer joins if the structure is so that the data might not exist.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps one or more of the other tables has no matching record.  If so, an `INNER JOIN` to that table will cause no rows to be returned.

You may want to try a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so that you'll get all the contents from the tables on the left side of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT        Registration.RegID, Registration.BoardNo, Registration.Name, Registration.Gender, Registration.DOB, Registration.RationCardNo, Registration.F_H_Name, 
                 Registration.VoterID, Registration.Eligibility, Registration.PanNo, Registration.Categary, Registration.BankAcNo, Registration.Bussiness, Registration.Phone, 
                 Registration.Address, Registration.Photo, Nominee.NomineeName, Nominee.Relation, Nominee.Adult, Nominee.NDOB, Nominee.Guard_Address, 
                 Nominee.EnrollDate, MemberDetail.F_M_Number, MemberDetail.No_of_Dependent, MemberDetail.Land_Owned, MemberDetail.HouseNo, MemberDetail.MAddress, 
                 MemberDetail.BuiltArea, MemberDetail.HCost, MachinaryDetail.Head, MachinaryDetail.Number, MachinaryDetail.MCost
FROM            MachinaryDetail 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MemberDetail ON MachinaryDetail.RegID = MemberDetail.RegID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Nominee ON MachinaryDetail.RegID = Nominee.RegID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Registration ON MachinaryDetail.RegID = Registration.RegID
WHERE RegID='BS-ksd2'
```